# Datanucleus Performance difference between it's JPA & JDO Implentation against RDBMS?

Tags: jpa, jdo, datanucleus

Does anyone happen to know if there is a performance difference using Datanucleus JDO against a Relational Database (e.g. MySQL) in which the same application code and stack is used against the same Relational Database (e.g. MySQL) using again Datanucleus, but with JPA instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be no difference at all ... **when you have the same persistence properties selected**. The API layer is just that, translating from a standard API into an internal API (pass through in the vast majority of operations). All persistence properties are available for JDO or JPA. Similarly you can use the very same persistence classes (JDO or JPA metadata) with either API, hence no difference in time there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  May I ask just one more question please: In the [Datanucleus website](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_1/guides/jdo/tutorial.html) it states: '_Any good JDO book will provide many examples_', and I have searched the net quite thoroughly, but could not find any books or good tutorials on JDO 3.0 that is recent.  Can you direct me to one?

Comment: Nobody has written a book specific to JDO3, but there are various for JDO1 that describe the API itself and that hasn't changed. In terms of examples/tutorials the DN site in the docs for each release has various samples/tutorials, the DN tests (public SVN) are all good examples of JDO persistence, as well as a real world servlet style example (written for DN2.x) http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/guides/jobfilter/index.html

Comment: Thanks Andy for your answer. I'd like to ask this final question (and if you like I can make this into a new question)...Do you have any approximations with regards to performance difference between Datanucleus JDO/MongoDB vs direct MongoDB query and also for JDO/Neo4J vs direct Neo4J query in a scenario of say: 100,000 users access at the same time for reading an object that has 10 string attr and a collection of 30 classes and these having just 5 string attr with user base of 700,000? Also, with same scenario for new or updates, but with 10,000 users updating at the same time instead? Thanks

Comment: Anyway, thanks for answering my other questions.  Please note, that I delayed ticking the answer in case my comments did not reach you, but I did up vote your answer without delay.